# Underscore in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What does the underscore after "state.triggeredTests =" mean:

```
mutations: {

setTriggeredTest(state, data) {

  state.triggeredTests = _
    .chain(data)
    .forEach((item) => {
      item.dateFormatted = moment(item.date).format('DD MMMM YYYY');
      item.explanationTest = testMapping.get(item.test);
    })
    // .sortedUniqBy('explanationTest')
    .orderBy('date')
    .groupBy('date')
    .value();
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a library of function/utilities/helpers which generally can be either [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10) or [underscore](https://underscorejs.org/)

Comment: so, it is something like a namespace in C++ ?

Comment: Sort of, `_` is a valid variable declaration allowed in Javascript, so libraries like underscore or lodash just use that declaration using `var _ = (function() {...})();` to point to their public functions which are available to you and which may or may not be chainable depending on library. Similar example is `$` declaration which usually people identify as `jQuery` or `Prototype` library.

Answer (score 3):

`_` is the completely valid identifier in JS. `_` global variable is being traditionally used by the [underscore](https://underscorejs.org/) library and its clones as a namespace.

P.S.: `$` is the valid identifier as well, and it's being used by [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) or similar libraries.

Comment: Worth noting that OP's example is actually [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#chain) as opposed to underscore, AFAICT.